# mysqldump: Couldn't execute. Unknown table 'column_statistics' in information_schema

Tags: mysql

I want to dump my database, even after following correct syntax it thows me following error.

Syntax I used :

`mysqldump -uroot -p omnichannel_store_india > omnichannel_store_india.sql`

**Throws errors :**

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute
>    'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"') FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'omnichannel_store_india' AND TABLE_NAME = 'consignment_items';':

**Unknown table 'column_statistics' in information_schema (1109)**

Comment: Same question on Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/912162/mysqldump-throws-unknown-table-column-statistics-in-information-schema-1109

Answer (score 223, accepted):

This is due to a flag `column-statistics` that is enabled by default in mysqldump 8. You can disable it by adding `--column-statistics=0`.

The command will be something like:

```
mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --host=<server> --user <user> --password <securepass>
```

To disable column statistics by default, you can add the following in a MySQL config file, such as `/etc/my.cnf` or `~/.my.cnf`.

```
[mysqldump]
column-statistics=0
```

It's brilliantly working for me.

More details about `column-statistics`:

> Add ANALYZE TABLE statements to the output to generate histogram
> statistics for dumped tables when the dump file is reloaded. This
> option is disabled by default because histogram generation for large
> tables can take a long time.

Ref: [MySQL official documentaion
link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_column-statistics)

Comment: I was getting this error thrown from PhpStorm when using windows mysqldump.exe. If this is you as well, you can apply this solution manually by adding `--column-statistics=0` in the window below the "Out Path" since there is no checkbox for column statistics.

Comment: It would be really helpful to say why this happens. I assume it's because you were using an older MySQL server instance (or a MariaDB server instance, as @terry zhang suggests)

Comment: @stephenfin,  if I recalled the situation correctly, that could be due to a version mismatch b/w the Mysql client and MySQL server.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, we using mariadb-server and mysql-client(8.0). The column-statistics was introduced on mysql-client 8.0.
The quick fixed way it that remove the mysql-client and install mariadb-client.

On ubuntu 20.04, the command is:

```sh
apt remove mysql-client
apt install mariadb-client
```

Comment: It definitely was a client issue. I tried this solution on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and resolved the fault; thanks-

Answer (score 2):

Since i cannot comment the actual answer from user:Amitesh Bharti, i'm adding a slight variation of the actual answer. In my case i had to change it in `/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf` and i had to leave it in the `[client]` section so not adding a `[mysqldump]` section.

So for me this was working `/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf`

```
[client]
column-statistics=0
```