# How to get download a sql dump from docker MYSQL container from terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, dump

How to get download a SQL dump from docker MYSQL container from terminal

**Version:** mysql:5.7

I need to download a SQL dump, from the docker container. The database is available inside the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

First we should be aware of running MySQL container host & port.

If you are not aware of it, please refer this link [How to Find Running Docker container host & port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70232853/how-to-find-running-docker-container-host-port)

This is the command to download the mysql dump in terminal

`mysqldump -u root -p  --column-statistics=0 --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3310 local_db > localDb04Dec2021.sql`

1. Why we have added in this flag `--column-statistics=0` Refer this link to know [mysqldump: Couldn't execute. Unknown table 'column_statistics' in information_schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423595/mysqldump-couldnt-execute-unknown-table-column-statistics-in-information-sc/52423596#52423596)
2. Hostname for this container is 0.0.0.0
3. Port 3310
4. `local_db` is the name of the mysql database
5. Dump file name is `localDb04Dec2021.sql`
6. After run this command the dump will be available is the path, which you are running this command
7. If you not aware of the current path, get to know by hit this `pwd` command